# Как проверить массив на уникальность

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста одну вещь, как проверить массив на уникальность value и вернуть true если это не так. я сделал это через foreach. Может есть какой способ попроще?

Comment: зависит от того, как выглядит массив с данными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря какой массив, какие данные и на сколько глубоко надо копать.

С самым простым массивом можно делать так:

```
$arrayInput = [1,2,3,4,2,3,2];
$arrayUnique = array_unique($arrayInput);

if (count($arrayInput) === count($arrayUnique)) // тут ещё можно применять array_diff или array_intersect
    echo 'Уникально всё';
else
    echo 'Есть не уникальное';
```